# CREATE & UPDATE Record with one action method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a Model:

```
public partial class BusinessTypes
{
    public BusinessTypes()
    {
        CompanyBtype = new HashSet<CompanyBtype>();
    }

    public int BtypeId { get; set; }
    public string NameEn { get; set; }
    public string NameFr { get; set; }
    public string NameAr { get; set; }
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    public string StateDate { get; set; }
    public string LastModifiedDate { get; set; }
    public bool? IsActive { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<CompanyBtype> CompanyBtype { get; set; }
}
```

Then I have a View Model:

```
public class BusinessTypesViewModel 
{
    [Key]
    public int BTypeId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(200)]
    public string NameEn { get; set; }

    [StringLength(200)]
    public string NameFr { get; set; }

    [StringLength(200)]
    public string NameAr { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Country")]
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    public int SelectedCountryId { get; set; }
    public string SelectedCountryName { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Countries { get; set; }
}
```

Then in Controller, I am doing something like this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(int? id)
{
    var country = new SelectList(await _context.Country.Where(a => a.IsServiceAvailable == true).ToListAsync(), "CountryId", "NameEn");
    BusinessTypesViewModel viewModel = new BusinessTypesViewModel();
    viewModel.Countries = country;

    if ((id == 0) || (id is null))
    {
        //viewModel = await _context.BusinessTypes.FindAsync(id);
    }
    else
    {
        var businessTypes = await _context.BusinessTypes.FindAsync(id);
        if (businessTypes == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        viewModel.NameEn = businessTypes.NameEn;
        viewModel.NameFr = businessTypes.NameFr;
        viewModel.NameAr = businessTypes.NameAr;
        var selected = viewModel.Countries.Where(x => x.Value == businessTypes.CountryId.ToString()).First();
        selected.Selected = true;
        viewModel.SelectedCountryName = selected.Text;
    }
    return View(viewModel);
}


[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(int id, BusinessTypesViewModel btypesViewModel, BusinessTypes btype)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (id == 0)
        {
            btype.NameEn = btypesViewModel.NameEn;
            btype.NameFr = btypesViewModel.NameFr;
            btype.NameAr = btypesViewModel.NameAr;
            btype.CountryId = btypesViewModel.CountryId;
            await _context.AddAsync(btype);
        }
        else
        {
            _context.Update(btype);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }
    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
}
```

I want to use this Create Action for both CREATE/UPDATE with one model. On Edit Call, its going to this part of code:

```
else
    {
        _context.Update(btype);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
```

but rather UPDATING the record, its always adding one more. Can anyone help me where i am doing anything wrong or any suggestion. I want to use same view and action for both CREATE Record and UPDATE exiting one. Thank You

[image]

Comment: What's is the value of `btype.BTypeId`?

Comment: Its primary key in BusinessTypes Tabls from SQL Server. I am using DB First approach. All is working fine but on EDIT, its INSERTING new record. Thats the issue

Comment: You need to debug your code and check value of `btype.BTypeId`? It looks like this value is zero so EF is inserting a new record. You need to make sure that the value of `btype.BTypeId` is the id of the record so that it is updated instead of inserted.

Comment: I have debugged already. btype is returning the correct ID and in code its going to _context.UPDATE(btype) function ignoring _context.Add. But at the end Its inserting a new Record. I have added a debug screenshot also.

Comment: Did you notice BTypeId is zero for btype ? That's why it is inserting the new record. You need to do `btype.BTypeId = id;` before `_context.Update(btype);`

Comment: You are perfectly right. I got the issue. Thanks a Lot. Solved.